# Filtering pandas df with level values

Tags: python, pandas, list, filter, levels

I have the following pandas df:

```
df
                        price           max    maxperhour
Site  Commodity Type                        
Mid   Biomass   Stock     6.0  1.500000e+15  1.500000e+15
      CO2       Env       0.0  1.500000e+15  1.500000e+15
      Coal      Stock     7.0  1.500000e+15  1.500000e+15
      Elec      Demand    NaN           NaN           NaN
      Gas       Stock    27.0  1.500000e+15  1.500000e+15
      Hydro     SupIm     NaN           NaN           NaN
      Lignite   Stock     4.0  1.500000e+15  1.500000e+15
      Solar     SupIm     NaN           NaN           NaN
      Wind      SupIm     NaN           NaN           NaN
```

I would like to filter above mentioned df and create a list of `Commodity` items as a list, when `Site == 'Mid'` and `Type == ('Stock' or 'Demand')`.

**so following list should be created with some pandas filtering function:**

```
df.somefunction()
['Biomass', 'Coal', 'Gas', 'Lignite', 'Elec']
```

How would I achieve this?

---

Lastly if it is possible I would like to have `'Elec'` as the last element, what I mean is; when the list is created, `'Elec'` would be probably the third element of the list like:

```
['Biomass', 'Coal', 'Elec', 'Gas', 'Lignite']
```

However, it would be best if I can get `'Elec'` as the last element like:

```
['Biomass', 'Coal', 'Gas', 'Lignite', 'Elec']
```

since it is the only element with `Type == 'Demand'`

---

From @jezrael

```
df[(df.index.get_level_values('Site') == 'Mid') & (df.index.get_level_values('Type') == 'Stock')].index.remove_unused_levels().get_level_values('Commodity').tolist()
```

Comment: Do you think need compare number of filtered values with `Mid, Stock` and `Mid, Demand` and by length of output need join together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution with `MultiIndex`:

```
m1 = (df.index.get_level_values('Site') == 'Mid')
m2 = (df.index.get_level_values('Type') == 'Stock')
m3 = (df.index.get_level_values('Type') == 'Demand')

idx1 = df[m1 & m2].index.remove_unused_levels().get_level_values('Commodity')
idx2 = df[m1 & m3].index.remove_unused_levels().get_level_values('Commodity')

idx = idx1.append(idx2)
print (idx)
Index(['Biomass', 'Coal', 'Gas', 'Lignite', 'Elec'], dtype='object', name='Commodity')
```

Alternative with columns:

```
df1 = df.reset_index()
m1 = (df1['Site'] == 'Mid')
m2 = (df1['Type'] == 'Stock')
m3 = (df1['Type'] == 'Demand')

idx1 = df1.loc[m1 & m2, 'Commodity']
idx2 = df1.loc[m1 & m3, 'Commodity']

idx = idx1.append(idx2).tolist()
print (idx)
['Biomass', 'Coal', 'Gas', 'Lignite', 'Elec']
```

Comment: u are going over the lenght of the levels for the second requirement, but if the Demand are longer than it wont work, but still thank you for efford

Comment: @oakca - So not sure if understand, what is logic behind? Not length of outputs?

Comment: well it is not your fault the question is too specific... The logic behind was the Demand elements should be always in the end, but does not matter. I am getting a weird error with the first one, because I did not want to create m1 and m2 instead I wrote all of it in 1 line via: `df[df.index.get_level_values('Site') == 'Mid' & df.index.get_level_values('Type').isin(['Stock', 'Demand'])].index.remove_unused_levels().get_level_values('Commodity')
` and the error is

Comment: `*** TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''`

Comment: @oakca - What is your pandas version?

Comment: pandas version is 0.23.4

Comment: @oakca - So in real data failed `print (m1 & m2)` ?

Comment: Following fails :(, is it because I wrote it all in 1 line? `data['commodity'][data['commodity'].index.get_level_values('Site') == 'Mid' & data['commodity'].index.get_level_values('Type') == 'Stock'].index.remove_unused_levels().get_level_values('Commodity')` and the error: `*** TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'Index'`

Comment: @oakca - yes, there is problem, need `()` like `data['commodity'][(data['commodity'].index.get_level_values('Site') == 'Mid') & 
                  (data['commodity'].index.get_level_values('Type') == 'Stock')].index.remove_unused_levels().get_level_values('Commodity')`

Comment: @oakca - oops, there is necesary remove `comodity` like `idx1 = data[(data.index.get_level_values('Site') == 'Mid') & 
           (data.index.get_level_values('Type') == 'Stock')].index.remove_unused_levels().get_level_values('Commodity')`